# Overriding a method that exists in one version of an assembly but not another in C# .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, overriding

I have a class that is a subclass of one provided by a third-party library. My class needs to be compatible with multiple versions of this third-party library.  As such, development against this library is done at the oldest version of the library that we maintain compatibility with.

A newer version of the library has a virtual property that I need to override in my subclass.  This virtual property doesn’t exist in older versions of the library.

Is there someway I can override that virtual property in my subclass without breaking compatibility with the older versions of the library?

Simply creating a property of the same name will not work as the object is cast as the base class during runtime (and thus the virtual property will use what is provided in the base class, not my subclass).  And we cannot ignore the virtual property as it affects runtime operations with the newer versions of the library.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way for me to inject an override of that virtual property that only occurs when using that newer version of the library? (I can identify the library version at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wrapper around the third party library class and inject the different flavor of wrapper to be used for different version of thirdparty library.

E.g For a `LibClass` you will have `IWrapperLibClass` which will have the currently used public methods. Your current implementation should depend on `IWrapperLibClass` and based on the version of 3rd Party library you have to figure out the way to inject the Flavour of `WrapperLibClassFlavourA`

Comment: I think this is probably the only route available.  As such, I have created a separate assembly that I have two versions of: one that overrides the methods/properties and one that does not.  The main code extends the classes from that new library instead of the third-party directly.  And from there, I'll just deploy the appropriate one based on the third-party library.